# Using attribute domain and subtypes in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, classification, domains

I have a schema (attached) for a certain classification that I need to include in the data structure.
Is it possible to use subtypes and domains to get the proper solution?
Simply, How to represent schema levels in database structure with a minimum number of fields?

[image]

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what problem you're trying to solve.  Please provide some more information about what the subtypes would be (eg, at which level(s) of your diagram), what the domains would be, and what the behaviour should be in regards to domains for these subtypes.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, my question is it possible to perform all diagram levels in one field using subtypes and domains, and how?

Comment: You still haven’t explained what you want to do with domains. And please add any new information to your original post also.  You can represent each of those items as subtypes, but it will not retain the tree structure inherently.  You may be able to simulate the tree structure implicitly with a naming convention (as already used in your items), but without more information, it’s impossible to know if that would suit your situation.  There will certainly not be any inheritance from parent to child.